# Declaring and using delegates across usercontrols

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delegates

Am I missing something here, I have two usercontrols, both of which has an event which uses the same delegate, therefore I put both usercontrols in the same namespace, examples below

1st Control

```
namespace Standalone.Controls
{
    public delegate void onDataChanged(object sender);
    public partial class TestItemWeb : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        internal event onDataChanged DataChanged;
```

2nd Control

```
namespace Standalone.Controls
{
    public partial class TestControlWeb : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        internal event onDataChanged DataChanged;
```

However, when running it I am getting this error, I can't see where I am going wrong with this :

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'onDataChanged' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 13:     public partial class TestControlWeb : System.Web.UI.UserControl

Line 14:     {

Line 15:         internal event onDataChanged DataChanged;

Answer (score 0):

Convert your project to **Web Application** because **Web Site** is really a pain to work with.
Also, I see you're using some very odd convention for events.

In .NET event handlers generally have two parameters, one of them is `object sender` and the second one's type must be derived from `EventArgs`.  If you don't want to pass any information, just leave it `EventArgs` and pass `EventArgs.Empty`.

You don't need to define custom delegates for events—framework already provides you with a simple `EventHandler` and generic `EventHander<TEventArgs>` which allows you to specify `EventArgs` type when you want to transfer information.

I usually also write a helper `EventArgs<T>` class with a single `Item` property that enables me to quickly pass something without polluting the codebase.

Comment: to clarify some of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx